# Upload image file using href in move_uploaded_file( ) php

Tags: php

I need some advice and guide line.
I am trying to upload image into a folder using link. And I am unable to upload an image.
I am trying this code. This shows error message :

> [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

```
<?php

  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {

    if (file_exists("http://localhost.myimage.com/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "http://localhost.myimage.com/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }

?>
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destination of the moved file needs to be an absolute path to the server, i.e.

```
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supplying `file_exists` and `move_uploaded_file` with an URL. Try supplying a file on the hard drive instead. Change:

```
file_exists("http://localhost.myimage.com/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])
```

to

```
file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])
```

and similar to `move_uploaded_file` since that's where the error originated.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible this way.

You try to store the uploaded file on a wrong destination.

I assume you own "http://localhost.myimage.com/uploads/" and wan't to store the file under '/uploads/' in your server.

If your project is installed e.g. under /var/www/my_prj/

And your upload is under /var/www/my_prj/uploads 
then your code should look like:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

This only applies when '/var/www/my_prj/' is the DocumentRoot for your apache configured host.